# Issue calling externally assigned closure from IBAction

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have this `UIView` subclass:

```
class EmptyAlbumsView: UIView {

class func instanceFromNib() -> EmptyAlbumsView {
    return R.nib.emptyAlbumsView.firstView(owner: nil)! as EmptyAlbumsView
}

// MARK: - IBActions

@IBAction func didTapFreeAlbumButton(sender: UIButton) {
    print("Tapping button")
    print(didTapFreeAlbumButtonClosure)
    didTapFreeAlbumButtonClosure?()
}

@IBAction func didTapEventAlbumButton(sender: UIButton) {
    didTapEventAlbumButtonClosure?()
}

@IBAction func didTapWhatsTheDifferenceButton(sender: UIButton) {
    didTapWhatsTheDifferenceButtonClosure?()
}

@IBAction func didTapSubmitAlbumCodeButton(sender: UIButton) {
    didTapSubmitAlbumCodeButtonClosure?()
}

// MARK: - Public Properties
open var didTapFreeAlbumButtonClosure: EmptyClosure? {
    didSet {
        log.verbose("set to \(self.didTapFreeAlbumButtonClosure!)")
    }
}

open var didTapEventAlbumButtonClosure: EmptyClosure?
open var didTapWhatsTheDifferenceButtonClosure: EmptyClosure?
open var didTapSubmitAlbumCodeButtonClosure: EmptyClosure?

}
```

which I am initialising in a `UIViewController` as such:

```
 fileprivate func showEmptyAlbumsView() {

    let emptyAlbumsView = EmptyAlbumsView.instanceFromNib()

    emptyAlbumsView.didTapFreeAlbumButtonClosure = {
        print("hey")
    }

    view.addSubview(emptyAlbumsView)
    emptyAlbumsView.matchEdgeAnchorsOfView(self.view)

}
```

I can see the `Tapping button` log statement from `IBAction`, but the second log statement over there prints `nil`, as it appears the `didTapFreeAlbumButtonClosure` has not been set, and of course not getting called ever. I never see `hey` printed out.

However, in the `didSet` block I can clearly see the closure is getting set.

`EmptyClosure` is defined as `typealias EmptyClosure = () -> ()`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Perhaps your closure variable needs to be marked with @objc.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. But there must be some reason the closure isn't called. I was speculating there may be an issue finding the Swift closure.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after a lot of frustration, the problem was rather silly.

In the Interface Builder I had set the `File Owner` of the my xib to `EmptyAlbumsView`. That was causing the `IBActions` to be called properly but when I tried hooking up some `IBOutlets` I was getting KVC errors.

It appears the proper way to do this is leave the `File Owner` class empty, and set the root views of the xib to `EmptyAlbumsView`. Then I'd hook my IBOutlets and IBActions directly to the view.